# Does Spring Data support querying data from multiple schemas simultaneously?

Tags: spring-data-jpa

Suppose I have two schemas in one database. Each schema has a table named 'products' which has almost same columns, such as 'title', 'sku'.

I have an entity class as follows, which is mapped to the products table:

```
@Entity
public class Products {
  private String title;
  private String sku;
}
```

Now I would like to select 'title' and 'sku' from the two 'products' tables in these two different schemas, how can I do it in Spring Data or does Spring Data support this kind of feature?

Answer (score 0):

No it is not. In order to be able to query data from different datasources with `spring-data-jpa` you have to define two separate entity manager factories, two separate transaction managers and two different configurations with

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "emf1", transactionManagerRef = "tx1")
```

and

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "emf2", transactionManagerRef = "tx2")
```

respectively.
Then you will be able to create two different repositories and query your data.

To tackle your problem you can introduce an additional level of abstraction like `ProductService` where you'll inject your repositories and in load methods iterate through them, fetch and combine data from each repository.